# How to add dependencies inside setup.py file?

Tags: python, linux

How to add dependencies inside setup.py file ? Like, I am writing this script on VM and want to check whether certain dependencies like, jdk or docker is there or not, and if there is no dependencies installed, then need to install automatically on VM using this script.

Please do tell me as soon as possible, as it is required for my project.

Answer (score 2):

In simplest form, you can add (python) dependencies which can be install via pip as follow:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=["install-jdk", "docker>=4.3"],
    ...
)
```

Alternatively, write down a `requirement.txt` file and then use it:

```
with open("requirements.txt") as requirements_file:
    requirements = requirements_file.readlines()
    requirements = [x[:-1] for x in requirements]

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=requirements,
    ...
)
```

Whenever you'll execute `python setup.py install` then these dependencies will be checked against the available libraries in your VM and if they are not available (or version mismatch) then it will be installed (or replaced). More information can be found [here](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/).

Answer (score 0):

Refer the https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/develop/setup.py and check the `requires` variables.

You can refer many other open source projects

Answer (score 0):

You can add dependencies using [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html), however it can only check dependencies on python packages.

Because of that, you could check jdk and docker installation before **setup()**, manually.
You could call system like the code below and check the reponse.

```
import os
os.system("java -version")
os.system("docker version --format \'{{.Server.Version}}\'")
```